# From Bootstrap 2.3.2 to Bootstrap 3 how to change control group?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am in the process of upgrading the latest Bootstrap. However we use the following code a lot throughout all the forms

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

I am aware controls has gone in Bootstrap 3 and control-group has been replaced by form-group.

But once we have changed those once I can see that we still do not get the same view as before. This is the reason that Bootstrap 3 is focusing on Mobile first approach. to get the same style we probably need to use grid view to resize the width of the inputs.

But I cannot figure out how to display (where to display) the error validation message?

What would be the best code to replace these forms to get similar view?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 introduces the grid into your form layout. You need to start using the col- syntax to indiciate how wide your label and controls should be. You're also going to remove the controls class completely. Here's a fairly standard way to rework your HTML, but keep in mind you can have multiple col- classes per element to support a responsive layout.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Also, the inputs are expecting to have a `form-control` class on them, so you'll need to update your generator for that.

Comment: so I do not need to replace control-group with form-group?

Comment: @akdurmus Apologies, form-group. My bad. Also added a note about .form-control